# Install php 5.3.28 error 2356

Tags: php, apache, installation, runtime-error

I have Apache installed on C:\Apache\ and conf on C:\Apache\conf\

When I try to install php 5.3.28 on Windows 8.1 with Apache 2.2.x web server Module I have an 'error 2356' and the php install can not be done !!!

Any ideas ?

[image]

Thanks for your help...

Comment: Same problem in Windows Server 2008 R2 also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both PHP 5.2 and 5.3 are available for msi install from the archive page http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/archives/
scroll down and you will find versions upto PHP 5.3.27

Comment: I know but I get the message above on Windows 8.1 !

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the archived versions of 5.3.28 and 5.3.29 on windows.PHP.net/downloads/releases/archives/ are corrupt as evidenced by their file sizes, 848k vs 47MB for 5.3.27.

Answer (score 0):

Use VC6 version of PHP and download from http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/archives/
I used PHP 5.2.10 without this error 2356 on Windowc8.1 and Apache 2.2.25

Comment: Thx Veronica for the tip. But no way to use 5.3.x version with msi installer on Windows 8.1 ?

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same error in version 5.3.28. My OS version is win7.

I finally give up and turn to use the Microsoft web platform installer..It does helps and very convenient ,but the disadvantage is that it only supports window IIS server .

Answer (score 0):

I ran the install using archived version 5.3.28 but the install failed with the error code 2356. I ran the install using archived version 5.3.29 and it works. File size looks ok now.